# The bank/ a bank

Tags: grammar

Which one is the right one?

> I am not surprised that Mike is in prison. He robbed {a|the} bank two years ago.

Comment: In a small Western town in the 1860s, 'he robbed the bank' might well have been used. Though 'jail' would have been more customary. However, if a particular bank has not been specified either overtly, or by implication (as in the one-bank town), 'a bank' is correct. // With 'he broke the bank', there need not even be a bank, never mind a particular one, involved: this is an idiom.

Comment: a (any, some ) bank.   the (this, that) bank.

Comment: This is like asking if it should be "he robbed a bank" or "he robbed my mother". Both are equally grammatical. They just don't mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends about which bank you are talking about.

If you know which bank and the fact that he robbed **this** bank in particular is important, then use *"the"*.

If it does **not matter which** bank he robbed or if you do not know which bank it is, then use *"a"*.